# Организация mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте! подскажите пожалуйста как можно реализовать такую вот вещь. Имеется форма отправки сообщений. А Базу запись будет выглядеть так (id(auto_increment),author,text,date). Хочу дописать добавление фотографий к каждому посту, все было бы довольно легко если хотели бы добавить всего лишь одну фотографию(это решилось бы добавлением еще одного поля в таблице), но хочется сделать так что бы можно было добавлять например фотографий 5+,подскажите как это можно сделать ?! Привязать фотографии к конкретному посту если id поста(auto_increment) ? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создай отдельную таблицу с фотками, и не мучайся.

```
id post_id img_name
```

и вообще почитай что такое [AUTO_INCREMENT](http://phpclub.ru/mysql/doc/example-auto-increment.html)

Comment: Это как бы не проблема но как добавить post id в comment_id если ID записи auto_increment ?

Comment: а зачем тебе его туда добавлять? изменил ответ, я думал тебя там комментарии

Comment: вы опишите сценарий добавления фотографий, чтобы всем было понятнее, как все происходит.

Answer (score 1):

Можете создать также дополнительное поле и хранить изображения в виде массива в формате JSON..

Это так... про между прочим..